# Array Merge based on two value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like:

```
Name  Qty Price
happ   1   50
happ   1   50
happ   1   50
happ   2   10
app    1   50
app    1   50
app    1   50
app    2   10
```

and I have to convert and merge  like that using JavaScript /jquery:

```
Name  Qty Price
 happ   3   50
 happ   2   10
 app    3   50
 app    2   10
```

based on equal name and price

Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: What you've done so far?

Comment: @IqbalFauzi I have only created a javascript array but can not find how to do like above with this.

Comment: Can you post your array ?

Comment: You need to try to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Happy The SO community would be more inclined to help if you show all your effort and research done so far including the javascript code attempts.

Answer (score 2):

I love such a tasks. They are not a difficult one and help to switch myself into working condition.

```
// Sample data
arr = [{ name: 'happ', qty: 1, price: 50 },
       { name: 'happ', qty: 1, price: 50 },
       { name: 'happ', qty: 1, price: 50 },
       { name: 'harr', qty: 1, price: 50 }];
result = {};

// Summarize array by one walk
arr.forEach(function(k) {
  if (!result[k.name + k.price]) {
    result[k.name + k.price] = k;
  } else {
    result[k.name + k.price].qty += k.qty;
  }
});

// convert object to array by one walk
var finalResult = [];
for (var key in result) { finalResult.push(result[key]) }
```

Comment: Note about the combination of `k.name + k.price`, if the name is like `happ5` and the price is `15`, we have `happ515`, in some other case if we have name is like `happ51` and the price is `5` then we also have `happ515`. So the keys are duplicated. However such a case is not pupular, we can always use some GUID token to ensure such a case never happens.

Comment: @yarix It is working fine but it also modify main array (arr).How can I stop this to modify main arraybecause I have to use for next time also.

Comment: @Happy you need to copy object instead of assigning it `result[k.name + k.price] = k`

Answer (score 1):

This problem is equivalent to the SQL query:

```
SELECT name, sum(qty), price 
FROM dataObject
GROUP BY name, price
ORDER BY sum(qty) DESC
```

You can use the native functions `.reduce()` to aggregrate the data, and then `.sort()` to sort by `qty`:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
// Sample data
arr = [{ name: 'happ', qty: 1, price: 50 },
       { name: 'happ', qty: 1, price: 50 },
       { name: 'happ', qty: 1, price: 50 },
       { name: 'happ', qty: 2, price: 10 },
       { name: 'app', qty: 1, price: 50 },
       { name: 'app', qty: 1, price: 50 },
       { name: 'app', qty: 1, price: 50 },
       { name: 'app', qty: 2, price: 10 }];

var groupedObjects = arr.reduce(function(res, obj) {
    if (!((obj.name + obj.price) in res))
        res.__array.push(res[obj.name + obj.price] = obj);
    else {
        res[obj.name + obj.price].qty += obj.qty;        
    }
    return res;
}, {__array:[]}).__array
                .sort(function(a,b) { return b.qty - a.qty; });



// print results for testing
_.each(groupedObjects,function(obj){
    var output = '';
    _.each(obj,function(val,key){
        output += key+': '+val+'<br>';         
    });
    output += '<br>';
    $('#results').append(output);
});
```

**Output**:

```
name: happ
qty: 3
price: 50

name: app
qty: 3
price: 50

name: happ
qty: 2
price: 10

name: app
qty: 2
price: 1
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/gTv7Q/)

Comment: It is working fine but it also modify main array (arr).How can I stop this to modify main arraybecause I have to use for next time also.